# How to maintain Standard Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I already have experience with Rails development process but i still have confusion about to maintain standard development of Rails Application, mean how to maintain standard of assets, views format etc.. can anyone explain about standard rails application repo

Answer (score 0):

Read this  [rails style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide).

You will get a better picture about folder structure and standards about Rails.

Comment: hmm.Thanks but i'm not expecting coding style

Comment: standard way to create rails repo which can include all default gem https://github.com/thoughtbot/suspenders